# JavaScript regex match any non white-space character except /

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have the following string:

```
/user/getMyId
/user/2423432
/user/32324/test
/user/32432232432
/user/sdafdsafdasfsda
/user/sdafdsafdasfsda?filter=sdafdsaf
```

What I want is to write a regex that matches all the URL that has two part except the first one `/user/getMyId`.
My expectation is it return all URLS except first one `/user/getMyId`, and third one `/user/32324/test`

My current regex is like:

```
/(:?(\/user\/(?!(getMyId))(\S+)))/
```

But it's not working.

Comment: On what grounds is the third URL being disqualified?

Comment: Any specific reason behind excluding these two? Do you want to extend the logic from these *two* to more later?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What i want to do is match all urls start with `/user/` and followed by non white-space character except `getMyId`, and `/everything`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negated character class to match any character but not of space or `/`

```
string.match(/^\/user\/(?!getMyId)[^\/\s]*$/m)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/1o4xr6/2)

```js
var data = [
  "/user/getMyId",
  "/user/2423432",
  "/user/32324/test",
  "/user/32432232432",
  "/user/sdafdsafdasfsda",
  "/user/sdafdsafdasfsda?filter=sdafdsaf",
  "/user/sdafdsafdasfsda?filter=sdaf dsaf"
]
var regex = /^\/user\/(?!getMyId)[^\/\s]*$/m;
data.forEach(function(str){
  console.log(str, regex.test(str))
});
```

Comment: use this `^\/user\/(?!getMyId$)[^\/\s]*$` if you don't want to match `getMyId` but `getMyIdfoo`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have limited exceptions, I would suggest you to make a regex that handles/ validates exceptions and use it to filter.

This way you can create a list of exceptions and then create a dynamic regex

```js
var data = [
  "/user/getMyId",
  "/user/2423432",
  "/user/32324/test",
  "/user/32432232432",
  "/user/sdafdsafdasfsda",
  "/user/sdafdsafdasfsda?filter=sdafdsaf"
];
var exceptions = ['getMyId', 'test']
var regex = new RegExp('/' + exceptions.join('|'));
data.forEach(function(str){
  console.log(str, regex.test(str))
});

var result = data.filter(x=> !regex.test(x));
console.log(result)
```